# Need your advice to choose between Pentaho and Spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch, pentaho, etl

I'm developing a java web application with **Spring framework**. And the main idea is to develop an **ETL** (for Extract , Transform,Load ) which extracts data from different databases and then load them in the same database.

I did a research , I found that **Pentaho** has a java API which let me do that work also it's a `BI` solution  ,But documentation is too poor.

I'm used to using Spring batch and Here I'm not able to know the difference between them. Because Spring batch also let me do reading data from databases, process them and then store them.

Is the `spring batch` solution an **ETL**  ??
Is `pentaho` more powerful or what shall I choose  ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: there's no help ? :'(

Comment: Spring Batch is not a real ETL tool, it is a framework to build tools, the question is, do you want a use-ready ETL tool or build your own?

Comment: I want to use a ready ETL , 
I want to extract data from many Csv files and load them in a same  database.